# Is 'metacogniscent' a word?

Tags: meaning, is-it-a-word

I was watching [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ALjL-t6h6Yo&lc=sKHj52E62kDm2ng2LYhnX_iLISvGvkYT6y3uL7INmpU) video and around the 1:05 minute mark the girl said 'metacogniscent', but I'm wondering whether or not that actually is a word, and if so; did she use it correctly (from what I've googled, the definition of 'metacognition' deviates from her definition of 'metacogniscent')

Comment: don't tell anyone, but which file formats can be used to show that video which I cannot open. I use Windows XP, however a safe way might be using a hyphen: meta-cogniscent.

Comment: He who knows not and knows not that he knows not is a fool; avoid him.
He who knows not and knows that he knows not is a student; teach him.
He who knows and knows not that he knows is asleep; wake him.
He who knows and knows that he knows is a wise man; follow him. Categories 2 and 4 seem to qualify as 'metacogniscent'. I'd say that there are some very informative articles on 'metacognition' on the web; that at Wikipedia shows that the term, new though it is, is typically polysemous: 'Different fields define metacognition very differently.'

Comment: @EdwinAshworth  I can't justify *cogniscent*, much less *metacogniscent*. Should be *(meta)cognizant* or *(meta)cognoscent*.

Comment: StonyB:  I've heard of cognoscente, but not cognoscent.  Please explain.

Comment: @rhetorician  *Cognition* (like the Italian *cognoscente*) derives from Latin *cognoscere*, of which the present (active) participle is *cognoscens, -entis*. *Cognizant* derives from the same participle, but via French *co(g)naissance*. [*OED*](http://archive.org/stream/oed02arch#page/598/mode/2up) actually lists *cognoscent* and gives 17th and 19th century citations.

Comment: We can learn a lot from StoneyB.

Answer (score 3):

She said *meta-cognisant* (AmE, *meta-cognizant*) which is a word, in that it is *cognisant* with *meta* prefixed.

Comment: The OED gives *cognizant* as the first spelling, and its citations are all British ones using the *-z-* form.

Comment: The OED (and I think OUP generally) is well-known for preferring -iz-, unlike nearly every other British institution.